# PowerPoint JS API: insert an image and set the title at the same time

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I am using [Script Lab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/) to build my add-in for PowerPoint on the web. I want to insert some images and encode extra information for each image in the title. The information I want to store depends on the content of the images.

From the example provided by Script Lab, I can insert images by calling [`setSelectedDataAsync(data, options, callback)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview#office-office-document-setselecteddataasync-member(1)) . However, this API doesn't provide any option to set the title of the image.

I have a workaround. After inserting the image with [`setSelectedDataAsync(data, options, callback)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview#office-office-document-setselecteddataasync-member(1)) , the inserted image will be selected. I use

```js
PowerPoint.run(
  async (context) => {
    const selected = context.presentation.getSelectedShapes();
    /* do something */
  }
);
```

to query the selected image and modify the title. The problem with this workaround is there is a time gap between insertion and the query of selected images. My users may do some actions to interrupt the whole process. Additionally, `getSelectedShapes()` is quite slow when there are many pages or shapes in the slides.

Is there a way to insert and set the title of it at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set a title when images are inserted in Office JavaScript API. As a possible workaround, you may consider displaying a progress dialog box to a user to prevent them from editing something on the page.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.